# How do you create a grouped barplot in R from only certain columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like

```
Role <- letters(1:3)
df <- data.frame(Role,
                 Female1=c(1,4,2),
                 Male1 = c(3,0,0),
                 Female2 = c(3,5,3),
                 Male2 = c(1,3,0),
                 FemaleTotal = Female1+Female2,
                 MaleTotal = Male1+Male2)
```

And want to create a barplot grouped with Male,Female for each column category, (in this example it would be 1 and 2), stacked with Roles and also another plot with just the totals. To do just the totals I could use melt() and subset the dataframe to only have those columns, but that seems messy and doesnt help witht the main plot I want to make.

Comment: Did you try running your code? Does it work for you? The first line gives me an error `could not find function "letters"`. There is also an error in the `data.frame` call. Please make sure that the code that you are sharing is actually reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to reshape to 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -Role, names_to = c( "group", '.value'), 
          names_sep="(?<=[a-z])(?=(\\d+|Total))") %>% 
   pivot_longer(-c(Role, group)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = Role, y = value, fill = group)) + 
         geom_col() +
         facet_wrap(~ name)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Role = c("a", "b", "c"), Female1 = c(1, 4, 2), 
    Male1 = c(3, 0, 0), Female2 = c(3, 5, 3), Male2 = c(1, 3, 
    0), FemaleTotal = c(4, 9, 5), MaleTotal = c(4, 3, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Really helpful, thanks! Quick question, say I wanted to plot just Columns with a 1 and total how would I do that? Not familiar with pivot_longer so it all looks weird to me. Not really sure whats going on with the names_sep stuff either

Comment: @Adam you can `filter` after the second 'pivot' i.e. `%>% filter(name != "1") %>% ggplot(`

Comment: I can't seem to get the code to run, am getting this error message Error: Can't subset elements that don't exist.
x Locations 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. don't exist.
i There are only 0 elements.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 24 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].


I assume because of the name_sep part. For some mopre info my column names are actually more like "Female Applied X" and "Male Successful Y" if that helps.

Comment: @Adam Is it based on the same dataset on my post or a different one.  Can you use `dput` to show a small example that shows the error